# How to config C++ IntelliSenseMode with vscode settings sync plugin for both mac and windows 10?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have a macbook and a windows PC, use vscode with `settings sync`, `C/C++` plugins.

I found `"C_Cpp.default.intelliSenseMode"` value is not configured well on multiple platform. On macbook I need it be `"clang-x64"`, on windows PC I need it be `"msvc-x64"`. While `settings sync` plugin force only one choice, cannot be dynamic or local.

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Emmmm, I think I found a solution.

delete the `"C_Cpp.default.intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"` from settings.json file. Just leave this configure option empty, it seems `C/C++` plugin will make a default choice.